# Was I nearly involved in an accident?

Tags: website, uk, datasets, incidents

This is a while ago but it has been bugging me now and then.

On September 11 2011 (yes exactly 10 years after 9/11!) I was flying Easyjet 3467 from London Stansted Airport (STN) to Copenhagen (CPH). Scheduled departure was 18:40 local time but the flight was heavily delayed (around 4 hours as I recall) due to another bizarre incident.

Anyway, as we were finally sitting in the plane and taxiing, suddenly the pilot announces that he just got info that another airplane had been heading to land just where we were and had only been some 60 seconds away! A lot of passengers seemed to gasp for air and the pilot sounded quite shocked as well. But there was no other explanation added.

Is there a database of such events so I could look up more about what happened?

I found the flight on [FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?airline=%28U2%29%20easyJet&flightNumber=3467&departureDate=2011-09-11&x=29&y=7) *(sign in required)* but there were no real info.

Comment: I cannot find anything in avherald, which is one of the leading sources for incident reporting: http://avherald.com/h?list=&opt=1&offset=20110911000000%2B4798675c

Comment: Runway incursion? not common, but not unheard of. Usually caused by mixup between ground control and the tower.

Comment: OK thanks didn't know avherald.com. But yeah can't find it either. Maybe it wasn't so serious after all or it didn't get reported. I will lookup runway incursion. Thx :)

Comment: Why on earth would a pilot announce that and panic people? Surely you have misunderstood and he was explaining a delay or something like that?

Comment: @JamesRyan: I agree and of course it is a possibility I misunderstood. But as I mentioned, the rest of the passengers gasped for air. Of course it could be he just told a joke and I sort of misunderstood the whole situation. That's why I would have liked to find a written record etc. of it (if it exists) because it has been nagging me over the years

Answer (score 20):

No, you were not nearly involved in an accident.

If the flight crew is ready to go, an Airbus A320 takes about 40-50 seconds from the moment take-off clearance is given until lift-off. As soon as the aircraft is off the runway, the next one can land. On some busy airports, 60 seconds between take-off clearance and the next landing is a daily occurrence.

In 60 seconds, there is a lot that can prevent an accident. For example, ATC could instruct the incoming aircraft to go around should the departing traffic not be ready to take-off. This is quite a normal event which happens every day at busy airports around the world. In such a case, the aircraft ready for take-off would have to wait for the incoming traffic to pass overhead. It sounds like you may have experienced such an event.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zodQpfe7ecc) of something similar happening in Birmingham.

Since it is a 'normal' event, there is no central database that tracks these issues.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder why would the pilot announce that then?

Comment: @MatthewLock Even if it was an exceptionally unusual occurrence, the pilot's announcement did nothing other than create unnecessary concern among the passengers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's exactly why he's wondering why the pilot announced it.

Comment: @Nit the whole statement "finally ... taxiing ... just where we were" seems fishy. Most airports aircraft don't start taxiing anywhere close to where aircraft land. Seems either a case of bad memory or a pilot making a very bad joke.

Comment: If a departing aircraft is not yet off the ground when an arriving aircraft reaches decision height inbound for the same runway, wouldn't the arriving aircraft need to go around?

Comment: @jwenting Yeah, especially since Stansted appears to have only one (remaining) runway, the only way I can see that you'd be in a place where another aircraft is about to land is the situation mentioned here in DeltaLima's answer: you're departing from the runway it's about to land on. It doesn't look like you'd ever need to cross the runway coming from the passenger terminal there.

Comment: @reirab of course it would. And a smart controller would have either the departure delay until the arrival is on the ground, or have the arrival slow down to give the departure time to clear the runway. I've had such a situation happen once, flying from an untowered field. We entered the runway (C182 I think we were in), other aircraft was on short final, broke off the landing, and stalled trying to turn away from our departure path, crashing. I don't think either pilot had a good night's sleep that day.

Comment: @jwenting Yikes. This is why it's useful to announce that you're about to land on a runway or that you're about to enter a runway for departure at an uncontrolled field... and to listen for such announcements from others (and to look out the window before entering a runway.) That seems weird that they would actually stall and crash, though. You shouldn't normally be going _that_ slow on short final. A smart controller wouldn't have the departure delay until the arrival is on the ground if the departure is already on the runway, though. :) That would end very badly.

Comment: @reirab not sure what they did, but we circled and saw an aircraft lying in a ditch just outside the field perimeter. Could in theory have been another one, but how many aircraft do you get in trouble in a few minutes time on a GA field? :)

Comment: Yes one of the things I've been wondering is why the pilot would announce it. I don't remember for how long we had been taxiing before the announcement was made. I just remember we had left the gate. Since the plane was heavily delayed (due to a passenger from the previous trip who apparently were unable to leave the airplane, so we had to wait hours for an ambulance, apparently from a private health insurance, to get cleared to enter the airfield with a lift. It was on 9/11 which also delayed all of this!), it must have been quite late in the evening that this occurred.

Answer (score 4):

The term you want to look for is [not "accident", but "incident"](http://www.aviationpros.com/article/10374517/accidents-vs-incidents).

> To figure out whether or not a situation qualifies as an “aircraft accident” we must look to the definitions in Part 830. The NTSB defines an “aircraft accident” to mean “an occurrence associated with the operation of an aircraft which takes place between the time any person boards the aircraft with the intention of flight and all such persons have disembarked, and **in which any person suffers death or serious injury, or in which the aircraft receives substantial damage**.” The first portion of this definition is especially important to note for maintenance and ramp personnel. The initial threshold for classification as an aircraft accident is that the aircraft is being operated “with the intention of flight.”

Since no injury or damage occurred, the even would be classified as an "incident".

---

In the US, NASA runs the [Aviation Safety Reporting System](http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov), a publicly searchable database of accidents and incidents.  The data are mostly about events in the US, although some international incidents are included as well.  The incident you mentioned doesn't appear.

The European equivalent appears to be [ECCAIRS](https://ec.europa.eu/jrc/en/scientific-tool/eccairs-european-central-repository-aviation-accident-and-incident-reports).  Unfortunately, access to that database is "restricted to authorized authorities."

Comment: Thanks for info - could anyone with ECCAIRS access look it up? Any other suggestion of how I might obtain more info? Maybe I should contact the airport og airliner?

Comment: By the way, not sure if I agree about the incident/accident distinction. If what the pilot said was true it would have been an incident. My question specifically asks if I was _nearly_ involved in an accident, i.e. what could have been the outcome of this incident under the right (wrong) circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

There was probably no incident.

It just means your plane was ready to take off and had to wait longer than expected. Whenever a plane is ready to go the controller has to decide whether he can let it go or should wait for an incoming plane. The controller was probably just playing it safe and decided to make your plane wait, so the pilot got a little exasperated, "Sorry folks, got to wait for another plane to land."